# command line looking in wrong place

Tags: terminal, rubygems, osx-leopard

when i type

```
$ gem
```

in my terminal (mac osx) it says

```
-bash: /usr/bin/gem: No such file or directory
```

yes, i know theres no such file or directory, its in

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

why is it looking there?

```
$ echo $PATH

/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/mike/.local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

Comment: im not really looking to address the symptoms, i want to prevent it from looking here, why is it looking here?

Comment: Obvious I know, but which Ruby is your system using, the MacPorts version or the OS X one?

Comment: if i type
    $ which gem
i get
    /opt/local/bin/gem, PS, i didnt use macports. Also, if i type /opt/local/bin/gem it executes properly

Answer (score 1):

```
euclid:~ seth$ ls -l /usr/bin/gem
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  71 May  4  2010 /usr/bin/gem -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem
```

Just a guess, but if you used something like MacPorts to install a new version of Ruby, it probably broke the `gem` symlink in `/usr/bin`.

You can probably "fix" it by just making a working symlink:

```
$ cd /opt/local/bin
$ ln -s /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/usr/bin/gem .
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your .profile and add :/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 to the end of the path variable. But I would think this error means you didn't setup or install something correctly.

Comment: to the start, to avoid looking `gem` in `/usr/bin`